# Using Enum Flags How to?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

Currently I have 4 permissions in my website

```
Edit
Delete
Add
View
```

Everyone gets view permissions when someone subscribes to someone else.

Currently in I store each as a column in my database as a bit value.

I am thinking maybe I should use enum with flags but I have some questions.

1. The user will be able to choose the users permissions(eveyone gets view you cannot take that away). Right now it is easy as I use a checkbox and then save the bool value to the db.

My questions is what is the best way to convert checkboxes to the enum type? So if they choose add permission I can map that to the right enum type.

Wondering if there is a better way then

```
PermissionTypes t;
if(add == true)
{
   t = PermissionTypes.Add
}

if(edit == true)
{
   t += PermissionTypes.Edit // not sure if you even can do this.
}
```

I know with enum flags you can use the pipe and do something like this

```
PermissionTypes t = PermissionTypes.Add | PermissionTypes.Edit
```

I am wondering is it good practice to have another type in my enum like

```
AddEdit = Add | Edit
```

I am thinking that can result in many combinations(imagine if I had like 10 permissions or something like that).

Comment: What you have is pretty reasonable. The `|` equivalent for `+=` is `|=`.

Comment: You can use `if(add)` instead of `if(add == true)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enums are simply integers values. By settings your enum values to different power of 2, you can easily have any combination you need:

```
enum ePermissions
{

   None = 0,
   View = 1,
   Edit = 2,
   Delete = 4,
   Add = 8,
   All = 15
}

ePermissions t;
t = (ePermissions)((add?ePermissions.Add:ePermissions.None) | (delete?ePermissions.Delete:ePermissions.None) | ...);
```

if you want to know if some user has the Add permission just do as follow:

```
canAdd = (currentPermission & ePermissions.Add) != 0;
```

Comment: Why is All = 15? Would have thought it would be 16(I know the other add up to 15) since that is power of 2.

Comment: All = View | Edit | Delete | Add = 15. It is not a sum per see, but a bitwise OR. Basically, if we look at it in binary code this would be: 1111, 1 bit for each operation.

Comment: More visually apparent is to use `All = View | Edit | Delete | Add`.

Answer (score 0):

On converting set of `bool` values to enum - for small set `if` would be ok. You can also use `?:` operator to do the same in smaller number of lines:

```
[Flags]
enum Permissions 
{ 
   None = 0, 
   View = 1, 
   Edit = 2, 
   Delete = 4, 
   Add = 8, 
}

var permissions = 
  (add ? Permissions.Add : Permissions.None) |
  (edit ? Permissions.Edit : Permissions.None) |
  (delete ? Permissions.Delete : Permissions.None);
```

If you have large number of values some sort of mapping of Control to Enum may be useful.

On `AddEdit` - this particular on is probably not useful. You can as easily write `Add | Edit`. Some menaingful combinations of permissions (or falgs) may be named specifically if code will use such combination in meanigfull way. I.e. `CanModify = Add | View`.

Comment: it shouldn't be + (addition) but | (bitwise OR) operation. Although in this example, the result is the same. If we use +, there are some edge case we need to handle, like adding a permission twice for example.

Comment: @lcfseth, thanks for comment. I like `+` more for readability (purely personal preference), but I agree that in general case `|` is safer. Changed sample per your recomendation.